# Jquery confirm not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, button

I have a the following `<asp:Label.../>` :

```
<asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' ForeColor="Desktop" /></h4>
```

and this **html** `<button ... >` control :

```
<button id="btnAddToCart" runat="server" class="btn btn-1 btn-1c center" onserverclick="btnAddToCart_ServerClick" onclick="Confirm()"><span class="icon-shopping-cart"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;add to cart</button>
```

**P.S:** I have use a normal `<button>` and **not** an `<asp:Button../>` control because of the `<span class="icon=shopping-cart">` that i am using.. Using asp button control doesnt allow nesting of span class within it.

**Now,** i want that on the click of the button an alert should come with options YES or NO as it comes in `confirm("")` ..

I have written the following script :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#btnAddToCart').click(function () { //i have also tried $('.btnAddCart')...
            var productName = $('#lblName').val()
            confirm("Are you sure you want to add " + productName + "into your cart ?");
        });
    </script>
```

**P.S:** i have embeded the `script` into the body tag(which is the ContentPlaceHolder)
What is wrong with the script..  and also which way should i do the `confirm()` popup..?

Also, I have the `label` and `button` controls nested within a `ul-li` list!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your button to:

```
<button id="btnAddToCart" ClientIdMode="Static"
```

Your jquery isn't working because your button ID isn't "btnAddToCart" it's the concatenation of all the naming containers + "btnAddToCart". That's the default ClientIdMode. You want static, which is basically telling asp.net "Don't worry. I know what I'm doing. There will only ever be one of this control on a page with this id."

See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx for more.

Comment: 1) using `ClientIdMode` raises error of not allowing uppercase letters in `<button>` control  2) i tried using `clientidmode`, and it doesnt work either!

Comment: removed the ClientIdMode from the `<button../>` control and instead gave the same attribute to the `@Page` attribute... still doesnt work!

Comment: It raises an error of not allowing uppercase letters? Huh? What is the exact error message?

Comment: The exact error is : `Validation(XHTML5): This name contains uppercase characters, which is not allowed.` and this is what i am writing : `ClientIdMode="static"`

Comment: That error is in the designer right? does the app run?

Comment: can u tell me some way to do this.. now that u know my requirements...? @aquinas

Comment: So, you added, "ClientIdMode="static"" and then you ran the app. In the HTML that got generated (in your browser, when you say view source), what is the id of the button?

Comment: Yes i did realise that the id is rendered differently... like `ct001$Label` .. But i found another way mentioned in my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using a `<asp:LinkButton.../>` is way more powerful than than using normal `<button.../>` control...

Instead of using :

```
<button id="btnAddToCart" runat="server" class="btn btn-1 btn-1c center" onserverclick="btnAddToCart_ServerClick" onclick="Confirm()"><span class="icon-shopping-cart"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;add to cart</button>
```

You can Use :

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkButton" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-1 btn-1c center" OnClientClicke="return confirm('Are you sure you want to add this product?')" OnClick="lnkButton_Click"><span class="icon-shopping-cart"></span>Add to Cart</asp:LinkButton>
```